# How to use 'or' operator, Limit & 'and' operator in a single query for Mongodb repository in spring boot

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

Below Query how to convert in **Monogo DB** query ?

```
select * from xyz where status = 'pending' or status = 'failed' and retyrCount <= 3 Limit 20;
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you Probably already tried, and your attempt somehow failed?

Comment: @Query("{ $or: [ { status: ?0 }, { status:?1 }],  retryCount: { $lte: ?2  }  }")
List<MailModel> findByStatusOrStatusAndLessThan(String status1, String status2, int retryCount);                                                                                                                             Yes I got it but only limiting the data is remaining. Hope so it will be done.